# Is it given that two lines are perpendicular if a right angle is shown?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, angle

If I have a diagram, like the following:

[image: Diagram]

And I want to make make a proof for something like how segment AB is $\cong$ to segment AC if segment BD $\cong$ segment DC (using Perpendicular Bisector Theorem), well to do this I would need to show that segment AD $\bot$ segment DC (or segment BD).

Can I state that it is a given that the two are $\bot$ because a right angle is shown (so this would be given), or do I need to say, first, that m$\angle$ADC = right $\angle$ (given), and then say that segment AD $\bot$ segment DC (def of $\bot$ lines)

Comment: Well, what, exactly, is known here?  If all you are given is that "BC≅ DC" then it isn't true.  In order to conclude that "AC≅ AC" you have to be [b]given[/b] that AD is perpendicular to BC.

Comment: @user247327 I am saying that it is given that $\angle$ADC is a right angle, by the way, might want to check your point names in your comment :]

Comment: Presumably you mean $BD=DC$ rather than $BC=DC$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Wow! I can't believe I didn't catch that, haha! Well, I fixed it now!

Comment: If the right angle (the yellow square) is given, then you can say that $BC\perp AD$.

Comment: @JulianMejia and I can write that as a given?

Comment: @BeastCoder2 I don't see why not.

Comment: @JulianMejia Alright, thanks! If you answer that I can make it the correct answer because it answered my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, If the right angle (the rectangle in yellow)  is given. I think is okay to say that $AD\perp BC$. Now, you say that then $AB=AC$ iff $BD=BC$ by using the perpendicular bisector theorem.

Even though this is fine, I think this is overkilling since it feels that the thing you want to prove follows trivially from this theorem.

Another way to prove this is by using Pythagorean theorem. $BD^2+AD^2=AB^2$ and $ DC^2+AD^2=AC^2$. If you substract these two equalities, you get $BD^2-DC^2=AB^2-AC^2$. So, $BD=DC$ iff $AB=BC$.